# ASP.NET Web API 2 - Filter POST requests by Query String

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

**I have 2 actions for POST requests on my Web-Api Controller:**

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/messages/{retire=retire}")]
public HttpResponseMessage Update(string retire, [FromBody] message m)
{}
```

And

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/messages")]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Create()
{}
```

When I do a POST request to the address `/api/messages?retire=true` the action executed is the second one, instead the first one that is the one I need to execute.

> How can I make **requests with query string** execute the first action, and request with no query string execute the second one?

If I delete the `api/messages` action, the mentioned requests work fine.
I thought about joining both together and filter the requests with an `if`, but I don't exactly know how.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The post URL should be /api/messages/true for the update method. Also the way you mentioned the route is not correct. It should be [Route("api/messages/{retire}")]

Comment: @MohanRamalingam but with `api/messages/true` query strings are not used and I need to use that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally solved with both actions separated with this syntax:

For `POST /api/messages?retire=true` requests:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/messages")]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Update(bool retire, [FromBody] message m)
{}
```

For `POST /api/messages` requests:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/messages")]
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Create()
{
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just do like this

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("api/messages")]
public HttpResponseMessage Update(bool retire, [FromBody] message m)
{ 
  if(retire)
   {
       // write the logic of your first endpoint
   }
  else
   {
       // write logic for second
    }
}
```

Comment: `retire` is type string and you are handling it like a boolean, did you mean `retire!=null`?

Comment: If you suspect that null could be passed in it, than you may make it as a nullable bool

Comment: @Iñigo Please upvote and mark as correct answer if it helped